# Path in freopen command C++

Tags: c++, windows

HEY i got need to change path in freopen comand.

```
freopen("out.txt","w", stdout);
```

i want to instead of using stdout, my path on for example D: drive.
Icant change freopen (i think) to other command as my program isnt working then.

Comment: Show a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem, and exactly state what the problem is. _"as my program isnt working then"_ isn't very useful for diagnosis.

Comment: Why not  `freopen("D:\out.txt","w", stdout);`

Comment: @Rama Caution with the `'\'` in a character literal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thx guys changing it to

```
 freopen("D:\out.txt","w", stdout);
```

works

Comment: Without escaping the backslash? Interesting.

Comment: ye it worked and saved properly